# External bibliography when using ieeeaccess as documentclass

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, templates

What is the right way to use external bibliography in an `ieeeaccess` document?

**Context**:

I have a `.bib` file filled with all the citation within the text. I need to use it in a template format (the IEEE Access). This template is used within Overleaf.

When inserting the lines:

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}

%.............

\reftitle{References}

\externalbibliography{yes}
\bibliography{refs.bib}
```

I have this error:

```
! Undefined control sequence. l.77 \externalbibliography
```

**Questions**:

1. Can I use an external `.bib` file in a template where the other reference are within the `.tex` file?
2. if so, which is the right `\usepackage{...}` to be included?

Comment: The solution in the comment does not work properly (maybe I did something wrong I guess) and other errors appear using `IEEEtran`. Is that format proper of another journal? The IEEE transaction should be the right target and not the IEEE access, isn't it?

Comment: thank you @KersouMan, I am going to investigate and I will let you know! thank you again

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Solution**:

Asking my office colleague expert on IEEE Access, the solution is just adding these two lines:

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{refs}
```

Where my bib file is `refs.bib`. It works properly as it is. No other packages are needed.

Comment: Thanks for this. I created account just to upvote.

Comment: I am getting `! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.` for some reason.

Comment: Never mind. I had an old `.bbl` file that was causing me trouble.